# Generic programming with ranges/views not templates?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I'd like to have function that accepts any container of a fixed type. For a example a function that will accept both `std::array<float,1>` and `std::array<float,2>`.

I thought this would be possible with ranges but I'm realizing my understanding is quite superficial.

I this possible without templates?

---

Edit: Can we define a type using the ranges library that will do the equivalent of span but will work for non-contiguous containers? Maybe I didn't phrase my question right, I probably meant view rather than container.

Comment: [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span)`<float>`?

Comment: `std::array<float, 1>` and `std::array<float, 2>` are distinct types. You can't write a non-generic function that accepts both. If you don't want to make your function a template, you effectively need to make the type you're gonna be taking type-erase the original container for you - but that will likely use templates internally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For contiguous ranges, you might use [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) (C++20):

```
void foo(std::span<float>)
{
// ...
}
```