# Why doesn't ranges provide a type erased view for non-contiguous ranges?

Tags: c++, iterator, c++20, c++-concepts, std-ranges

I would like to have a function that will take any range/view of a fixed value type.

```
int main()
{
    std::array<std::pair<int, int>, 2> a{...};
    std::array<std::pair<int, int>, 3> b{...};
    generic_fun(a);
    generic_fun(b);

};
```

Of course I could do

```
template <std::ranges::range R>
    requires std::same_as<std::ranges::range_value_t<R>,std::pair<int,int>>
auto generic_fun(R range)
{
    for(const auto& element : range)
        return element.first;
}
```

but then the visual studio ide doesn't know the type of `element`.

I was expecting the ranges library to have some type like

```
template <typename T>
struct view
{
    template <std::ranges::range R>
        requires std::same_as<std::ranges::range_value_t<R>, T>
    view(R);
    T* begin() const;
    T* end() const;
};
```

Which would give me ide support for

```
auto generic_fun(view<std::pair<int,int>> a)
{
    for (const auto& b : a)
        return b.first;
}
```

Why doesn't such a type exist in the ranges library? Is it technically infeasible to define a type that abstracts away all but the value type of ranges/iterators? Or does no-one care about doing this because the only reason is ide support?

I though it would be natural to have a type (templated on a given value type) that wraps a given iterator concept, but std doesn't define any. (If there's something to read on the internet about types that wrap concepts, could you point me there please?)

Comment: Are all your types `array`s? Your question only uses those as an example, and your hypothetical `view<T>` would only work for contiguous ranges... so if that's the case, then [this is the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68574006/2069064) with the same answer: use `span`.

Comment: Yes, that's my question. But I was looking for understanding of ranges and concepts, rather than to solve the problem that motivated the question

Comment: I mean, if the question is "why doesn't ranges provide a type erased view for a contiguous range?" the answer is "it does: `span<T>`". If the question is *not* that, it would be helpful to clarify what the question is. Perhaps, dropping the contiguous part?

Comment: @TomHuntington: Is this question *really* just about IDE support? Because neither the language nor the library exists to make your IDE happy. If you want to make it happy, then just use the actual type instead of `auto`. After all, you wrote it in.

Comment: @NicolBolas no, I wanted to know if type erasure actually is important.

Comment: @TomHuntington: Generally speaking, you would only use type erasure for an algorithm or other consumer of a range if you had *no other choice*. Really, the same goes for type erasure in all of its forms.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

range-v3 has this under the name `any_view<Ref, Cat>`, where `Ref` is the range's `reference` (not `value_type`) and `Cat` is the iteration category (which defaults to `input`). That would let you write a function like:

```cpp
int sum(any_view<int const&> v) { // <== not a function template
    int s = 0;
    for (int i : v) {
        s += i;
    }
    return s;
}

std::list<int> l = {1, 2, 3};
assert(sum(l) == 3);
```

The problem is, this range adapter is *extremely* expensive. Think about the way that iteration works. We have a loop like:

```cpp
for (; it != end; ++it) {
    use(*it);
}
```

Even for input iterators, that means you have to type erase:

- `operator!=`
- `operator++`
- `operator*`

And that's *three* indirect calls *per element* (either `virtual` function calls, or through a function pointer, depending on implementation). That's a lot of overhead, and it's very rarely something that you would actually want to use anyway. As a result, it was very low priority as far as range adaptors to add into C++20 and isn't even on our [plan](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2214r0.html) for adding range adaptors in the future.

Now, for contiguous ranges the story is a bit different, since you can always store just `(T*, size_t)` and it doesn't matter what the original range was. It's still type erasure, but it's free - there's no added overhead. So `span<T>` is great in that regard.

> Or does no-one care about doing this because the only reason is ide support?

There are situations where type erasure actually is important. Maybe you're storing a bunch of ranges of different types. Maybe you're hiding this across an ABI boundary. But IDE support seems like a very weak motivator for using type erasure - especially in a context like this where there is fairly significant performance overhead to doing this.

> [...] but then the visual studio ide doesn't know the type of `element`.

You could also fix that by not using `auto`.

Comment: When I already have `std::span` to use with `std::array` I can see how it's rarely something you would want to use. Is there a reason why `container<T>`  returns iterators of type `container<T>::iterator` instead of `iterator<T>` ?

Comment: @TomHuntington The iterator for `vector<int>`, `list<int>`, `deque<int>`, and `forward_list<int>` have very different characteristics - they couldn't all be the same type.

Comment: Interfaces aren't zero cost abstractions so we need concepts and templates, that's what makes c++ special. Thanks for your time!