# Update range on successive iterations based on strides (or other operations)

Tags: c++, stl, std-ranges

In the code below I can create the `strode_view` to store the view which strides the range so that I could work with it in different places (check the size, etc.). But I have to add a new variable while in real code the strode version should just “replace” the original range transparently.

I do striding for performance reason, so strode "version" is used only when data reaches some threshold.

Is there a chance to update the `range` (see in the last line of the code) so that this replacement is not visible for the code which will follow?

And if not, why?

**The code**

```cpp
#include <execution>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<float> values(10);
    std::ranges::iota(values, 0);
    auto range = std::ranges::subrange(values.begin(),values.end());

    std::ranges::for_each(range, [](auto& v) { std::cout << v << " ";});
    std::cout << std::endl;

    const int in_range_i_need_only = 3;
    std::ranges::for_each(range | std::ranges::views::stride(range.size() / in_range_i_need_only), [](auto& v) { std::cout << v << " ";});

    std::cout << std::endl;

    auto strode_view = range | std::ranges::views::stride(range.size() / in_range_i_need_only);
    std::ranges::for_each(strode_view, [](auto& v) { std::cout << v << " ";});

    // No way to assign here; is there a workaround?
    range = range | std::ranges::views::stride(range.size() / in_range_i_need_only);
}
```

The [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4YqKj9j14)

Per comments, the problem with the code above is that the type (and the essence) of the first range (on the right side of the assignment) (which is `range`) and second range (on the left side of the assignment) (which is `stride_view` over `range`) is different.

So I tried to get the view from the beginning to make the assignment possible (last 4 lines of code reworked to):

```cpp
    auto view = std::ranges::subrange(range);
    std::ranges::for_each(view, [](auto& v) { std::cout << v << " "; });

    // No way to assign here; is there a workaround?
    view = view | std::ranges::views::stride(range.size() / in_range_i_need_only);
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work either because although `view` must be a view by [std::ranges::subrange](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/subrange)

> The subrange class template combines together an iterator and a sentinel into a single view.

It is not and it is still a range and the left side of the last assignment must be `std::ranges::stride_view<std::ranges::subrange<...`

So, even the trick with views doesn't work, since the type is growing with every view pipe operation applied.

The difference is not only between `range` and `view`, but between types of each and every view view after pipeline operation application.

Is there a way to manage this and stay with one variable only without being forced to check which of ranges/views to use in the code which will follow. I need the code following later doesn't care about the changes in the range/view. Is this possible?

Comment: This seems impossible. You may still need to use `ranges::to<vector>()` for (inefficient) type erasure.

Comment: Seems you are looking for a type-erased view. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68584050/3966456) basically says it's not what you really want to do.

Comment: _Why_ should the same name refer to the original and subsetted ranges?

Comment: @WeijunZhou, 康桓瑋, I see the reasoning. With all this I would reword my question to "what is the reason to make ranges and views so different that I can't use them interchangeably"? We have great ideas of ranges and great tools for views, but we can't use them together other than in one way; get range and manipulate in views. Well, I got the idea, let's work with views only. I reworked to updating the view and this didn't work anyway. I will try to make it working and then will update the question with a new code.

Comment: @DavisHerring, why in the expression `x=x+1` the same name refer to increased value? Why don't we use `x_incremented = x +1`? Because we need to reuse x in the loops, etc. Why `range = std::ranges::equal_range(range,...)` we again use `range`? This is called `iteration` and we jump to the next round of iteration. The same comes here. Rest of the code doesn't care if the range was cut or not and doesn't want to make "if" checks and choose the correct variable. Somewhere it **could** be updated, I don't care, I work with range (either updated or original).

Comment: @康桓瑋, I put a little bit more explanations to the question to show what I want to achieve. Of course, `ranges::to<vector>()` not my way, since I work on big data and any such copy will kill both memory and performance. Maybe any tricks to stay with the same variable?

Comment: @WeijunZhou, I provided another idea to show how I imagine the solution. Am I correct that when you say "type-erased view" you mean exactly this? This is not about erasing the view type to get the underlying range, but this is about the types of the views themselves and differences of views between them alone? So, with "type-erased view" you mean just a view without growing type as a result of the applied pipeline operations? If so, I didn't catch the idea from the link you provided. Why in such a case should we have extra expenses on this?

Comment: @DamirTenishev: Of course we can increment an integer, because the (machine) instructions for operating on it are the same before and after the incrementation.  That's not true for "I changed the rules for how you iterate over this range", and it's not clear why you would be applying such a range-change **in** a loop (as opposed to looping over any one such range).

Comment: @DavisHerring, I can't get your question. Let me start with a very simple example. I iterate through the data array and gather some stats on data for every range that meets my predicate. So, I use `std::upper_bound` to get the new upper range and I use `it =std::upper_bound(it, v.end(), *it)` which gives me jump to another pack of data to consider. Real case are a little bit more complex to put in comments with some optimizations to search faster based on stored data specifics. How to you suggest to address iterator movement in this case?

Comment: You can just type-erase the pipeline. That is doable, the cost is the usual cost you need to pay for type-erasure: a virtual table for each type you want to erase, as well as some runtime overhead in efficiency due to virtual dispatch. It may be worth it if it outweighs the cost to construct and destruct a full container. Think of the pipelines like expression templates used for impl'ing `valarray`s. For `valarray`s `a` and `b`, `(a+b)*(a-b*b)` and `a/b+b/a` are also unrelated types. The transform is encoded in the typename hence they cannot be the same type. (To be cont'd)

Comment: When dealing with expression templates, if you need to do some iteration, the usual way is at some stage you convert it to an actual `valarray`. That makes things easier to reason about. Same here, the typical way is just convert the view to a container. However, if you really find the cost to repeatedly construct and destruct your container to be too high, as I said, you can choose to type-erase the pipeline, although it is not a common enough pattern to make it worthwhile to make it part of the std library.

Comment: Some notes on terminology, you keep stating `ranges` and `views` as if they are entirely different things, but actually all the `views` in your code example are also `ranges`. You're probably meant `owning ranges` or simply `containers`. I may write a full answer if you find the comments above make sense and help you understand the issue better.

Comment: @WeijunZhou, with this quote above "The subrange class template combines together an iterator and a sentinel into a single view." this makes me hard days. I used to OOP terminology, so if one thing (view) wraps another thing (range), this is not "view is a range". Only if views have inherited from ranges, I would understand "views are also ranges". Since I don't see any inheritance in code, I am failing to catch this. Maybe this kind of inheritance done by interrelations of their templates. Let me think about this twice some days before I ask you for full answer. Thank you again so much!

Comment: It is not inheritance. Ranges and views are not concrete classes, they are concepts that model properties of types. Since `std::ranges::view<T>` explicitly [requires `std::ranges::range<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/view) (or, using the terminology of concepts, `std::ranges::view<T>` subsumes `std::ranges::range<T>`), all views are also ranges.

Comment: @WeijunZhou, that's what I meant with "Maybe this kind of inheritance done by interrelations of their templates.". Thank you for pinpointing the exact relations. Let me read the code to better understand the root causes. It seems to me now that this static compile-time relation of templates is what makes the construct so fast and so rigit and now I think I understand what do you mean with trading types for virtual dispatch. This kind of templates relation could be simulated in run-time only via indirection like virtual dispatch.

Comment: @DamirTenishev: If all you want to do is update bounds and/or strides on successive iterations, that is doable, but you’d need to phrase the question to make that clear.

Comment: @DavisHerring, I revised the question and found only the title to be updated, since the question itself is worded, at least, neutrally. You are welcome to edit the question so that I could learn the better wordings for future. Can you, please step in with the solution? I still have to use iterators-style solutions and want to just to ranges here.

Comment: @DavisHerring, the only working solution I found so far is to use `std::ranges::views::stride(1)` when no stride is necessary. So, the code uses 1 or the necessary value. It works, but it is still interesting how to "update bounds and/or strides on successive iterations". This could help in other situations.

Comment: @DavisHerring, you said that update bounds and/or strides on successive iterations is doable. Could you please, provide your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's already largely stated in the comments, but the [answer](https://www.godbolt.org/z/8bsP19b8E) for the case where every evolution of the range in question is some stride over some subrange of the same base range (or at least the same *type* of base range) is

```cpp
void whittle(auto r) {
    int a = 0, b = std::ranges::size(r), s = 1;
    auto mk = [&] {
        return std::ranges::subrange(std::ranges::begin(r) + a,
                                     std::ranges::begin(r) + b) |
               std::views::stride(s);
    };
    for (auto v = mk(); !v.empty(); ++a, b -= b > a, ++s, v = mk()) {
        for (auto &&x : v) std::cout << x;
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Note that the subrange and stride must be used even if they do not restrict the range.  Note also that, because the type of the view is (as always) cumbersome to write out, we end up using a lambda to avoid **duplication**; furthermore, for many algorithms we don't need to actually **assign** to the view because there is only the one expression for it.  The above can be written more clearly as

```cpp
void whittle(auto r) {
    for (int a = 0, b = std::ranges::size(r), s = 1;; ++a, b -= b > a, ++s) {
        const auto v = std::ranges::subrange(std::ranges::begin(r) + a,
                                             std::ranges::begin(r) + b) |
                       std::views::stride(s);
        if (v.empty()) break;
        for (auto &&x : v) std::cout << x;
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Other **parametrized** views like `std::ranges::drop_view` could be used similarly; changing the *type* of the view does of course require some form of **type erasure**.  The type erasure might not apply to the view itself: a `std::ranges::transform_view` could be used with various transformations wrapped in the same type of `std::function`, for instance.

Comment: Thank you. Am I got the key idea correctly that `std::ranges::subrange` solves any task like that since it really makes a new range, dropping the underlying view type information? If so, this should lead to real evaluation of the range/view so that all the applied operations like drop/stride could be applied intermediately? As I see it, all these view operations are done in compile time with view types chains. So, if I want to drop the types I have to pay by runtime evaluation. Is this correct? I just can't see where the price for this comes in the example above.

Comment: @DamirTenishev: `subrange` _can_ be said to do type erasure, but only in that it replaces the type of a range with the type of its iterators (which might or might not be shared with another range type).  That, though, is what we need for erasing the difference between the whole range and, well, a subrange.  This process can of course be implemented efficiently for a lazy range only if elements can be skipped.  Yes, more type erasure carries more runtime cost; here that overhead is merely the bounds adjustments and striding even when they are trivial.